# .NET data binding

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have been developing in [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) 3 / [Flex Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder) 3 for a while now and am pretty comfortable with data binding when developing those types of applications.

Recently, I've gotten into some C# and for the life of me can't find a good reference on how to data bind.

I was wondering if someone could give me some info on how to data bind and perhaps some of the caveats found when binding in .NET (do's and dont's)

Comment: @Chris: You have to be more specific, are you using Windows Forms, or Windows Presentation Foundation.  They share some similarities, but there are major differences.

Comment: Are you trying to data bind winforms, wpf, ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an article about data binding in Windows Forms:

*[Windows Forms Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx)*

And in Windows Presentation Foundation:

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx*

And in ASP.NET:

*[ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)*

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken - it redirects to a generic page.